# Android getActivity() Context Goes Stale Over Time in PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-context, android-popupwindow

I have an app that uses a `popupWindow` for user chat. It is launched from a `Fragment`, and the supplied `context` is `getActivity()`. I will be typing in the `popupWindow`'s `multilineEditText` and, after about 5 minutes or so, I will consistently get a crash with this error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@d1cf1ec is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1147)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:471)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1621)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1375)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1341)
    at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.updatePosition(Editor.java:3817)
    at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:3773)
    at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:4287)
    at android.widget.Editor.replace(Editor.java:587)
    at android.widget.-$$Lambda$DZXn7FbDDFyBvNjI-iG9_hfa7kw.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

I know this isn't super helpful in explaining the error but, as far as I can tell, this is an issue with `getActivity` returning `null` and my `popupWindow` forcefully detaching from lack of `context`. Is there any way to avoid and/or fix this issue?

Below is some sample code for help with visualization of the `popupWindow` issue:

```
if(getActivity() != null) {

        //Retrieve layout inflater
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (layoutInflater != null) {

            //Inflate custom popup layout
            View inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_chat_layout, null, false);

            writeMessageEditText = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.writeMessageEditText);

            chatLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            //Read from bottom-up
            chatLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            chatMessagesRecycler.setLayoutManager(chatLayoutManager);

            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, displayWidth, displayHeight, true);

            popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);

            popupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
            popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

            //Cap message lines - the purpose is not to cap characters, but ONLY to cap length
            writeMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (writeMessageEditText.getLayout().getLineCount() > 150) {
                        if (writeMessageEditText.getText() != null) {
                            writeMessageEditText.getText().delete(writeMessageEditText.getText().length() - 1, writeMessageEditText.getText().length());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message may not exceed 150 lines", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            //This was implemented during testing - possible to remove but fine for now
            dismissChatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    resetAll();
                    previousChat = null;
                    if(popupWindow != null) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        popupWindow = null;
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: Nothing to do with a stale `Context`, or anything. That stack trace is saying that the `EditText` is trying to show a `PopupWindow` of its own, but you can't show one `PopupWindow` from another `PopupWindow`. They expect to be anchored to a `Window` – i.e., an `Activity` or a `Dialog` – and I don't think that there's anyway around that. The last time I encountered such a question, I think we ended up adapting their `PopupWindow` setup to use a `Dialog` instead.

Comment: Have you tried using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getActivity()`?

Comment: The crash occurs when I am typing into the edit text. I have a custom popup menu for copy/paste on long click that is anchored to the edit text, but it is never active at the time of crash as far as I am aware. I will disable it nonetheless and see if I can replicate the issue without it @MikeM.

Comment: @Mike087 I have in the past. It doesn't make any noticeable difference though.

Comment: It's not your popup. It's coming from the `EditText`'s `Editor`, which is a private helper that handles editing interactions. You could try to prevent them, but the one that's causing the issue currently – `SuggestionsPopupWindow` – is not the only `PopupWindow` that an `EditText` can show.

Comment: @MikeM. That's very interesting. Thanks for the insight. So then is there no way around the issue without removing the popupWindow? Also, do you know of any resources I could look at to understand this issue better besides documentation?

Comment: Not as far as I know. As mentioned, it would work inside a `Dialog`, and a plain one of those is not really any different than a `PopupWindow`, visually anyway, though positioning and sizing one is a bit different. As for the resources, I don't know that things like this would be documented anywhere specifically. I'm pretty familiar with how `EditText` works internally, and I've run into the `PopupWindow` issue before, so I just knew from experience what the stack trace was saying.

Comment: @MikeM. one more question then - if the context isn't stale or whatever and the issue is due to the Editor, why does it only seem to happen randomly? Everything works smoothly most of the time while I test the issue with erratic typing and editing...until it doesn't. Is this an instance of the editText popupWindow only launching when it crashes, or is it launching at other points before then as well (just without the crash event)?

Comment: Nah, if it pops, it crashes. There won't be any silent failures that you're missing. I'm not sure why you hadn't come across this earlier. I would've thought it'd happen pretty quick in testing. Think about how often any other `EditText` you type in will pop up its little floating menus or selection handles. FWIW, I reproduced it exactly as I was expecting, so I'm fairly certain I'm correct about this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijxLc.png.  However, I've also found several questions here with similar setups but no mention of this issue, so take that as you will. Maybe they came across it later.

Answer (score 0):

Despite being dead-wrong regarding the cause of the core issue I was experiencing, I figure I may as well leave the question up for people who are just as bad at reading stack traces as me.

This may not be the perfect solution but, thanks to Mike M.'s comments, I was able to solve the immediate issue by disabling suggestion popups for the `EditText` in the xml file like so:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Otherwise, the solution would be to replace the `PopupWindow` with a `Dialog` or `Activity`.